# SailsJs/Postgresql - How to create a one way association or one-to-many relation via an unique field

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I have two models:

**PdfAnnotation.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: "pdf_annotations",
  primaryKey: "pk_id",

  attributes: {
    pk_id: {
      type: "number",
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    annotation_id: {
      type: "string",
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    comments: {
      collection: "pdfcomments",
      via: "fk_annotation_id"
    }
  }
};
```

**PdfComments.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: "pdf_comments",
  primaryKey: "pk_id",

  attributes: {
    pk_id: {
      type: "number",
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    fk_annotation_id: {
      model: "pdfannotations",
    },
    comment_content: {
      type: "string",
    },
  }
};
```

When I run these codes:

```
PdfAnnotations.create({
  annotation_id: "test3",
});
PdfComments.create({
  fk_annotation_id: 'test3',
  comment_content: 'test',
});
```

I got this error:

[image]

I have followed the documentation: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many.
The difference between my implementation and the docs is: the constraint I used for **PdfComments** to **PdfAnnotations** via an unique field **annotation_id(string)** not the primary key **pk_id(number)**, so that I got the error.

***For some reasons I don't want to use annotation_id as a primary key (such as its type is string)***

I'm not familiar with Sails and its ORM, hope to see your help.

Comment: `fk_annotation_id` expects the actual primary key id from PdfAnnotations model. So the row which got created during `PdfAnnotations.create`, the `id` of that should be passed for `fk_annotation_id`.

Comment: Hi @khushalbokadey, below the database I set the foreign key (fk_annotation_id) on pdf_comments table to reference pdf_annotation via annotation_id, so is there any way to set foreign key on ORM with specific field, currently seems like Sails ORM linking models/collections with primary key by default. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
const pdfannotation = await PdfAnnotations.create({
  annotation_id: 'test3',
}).fetch();

const pdfcomment = await PdfComments.create({
  fk_annotation_id: pdfannotation.id,
  comment_content: 'test',
});
```